# Is there a way to get the created date of each line in a file that's version controlled with git?

Tags: git

Say I have a CSV created & committed on 2023-12-09:

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,val2,val3
val4,val5,val6
```

that was updated & committed on 2023-12-10 to:

```
col1,col2,col3
val7,val8,val9
val4,val5,val6
```

Is it possible to get a mapping of each unique line of the file history, and the date that it was introduced? The expected result would be:

| Line | Date |
| --- | --- |
| val1,val2,val3 | 2023-12-09 |
| val4,val5,val6 | 2023-12-09 |
| val7,val8,val9 | 2023-12-10 |

Comment: Humans can easily arrive at some common sense of "line identity" in this case, but try writing rules to assign identities to lines, you'll see the problem here.

Comment: Isn't this more or less what `git blame` and `git log -L` do?

Comment: Do you want to add a date for each line in your current file ? or do you also need to spot lines that were deleted/modified in this file's history, and get a date for these lines too ?

Answer (score 0):

From git straight? No.... A little bit of bash-fu should work Try doing a git log of that file only showing the commits (with pretty), then you could feed the list of commits into a `while read`, then you could take each revision and run git blame on it, remove the first line to not see the headers.... The output will be a stream of the lines with the date that each one was inserted (or modified.... But your scenario does not include modification so I assume it's full lines added/removed), then you can sort it and run `uniq`.... That should be more or less what you are asking for.... So, something like:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=%h the-file | while read commit; do
    git blame $commit -- the-file | tail -n +2 -
done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: the starting point would be a straight `git blame -- the-file`. The loop would be to loop over the lines and get the commit date for each leading sha.

Comment: Would not work.... Lines that have been removed in history of the file would not show up there